# Fatal error when using '#' character as an admin menu link title

Tags: admin-menu, fatal-error

When I try to title an admin menu link `#` or `&#35;`, I get a fatal error before the admin menu is loaded:

> Fatal error: Cannot access empty property in
>   /path/to/wp-includes/class-wp-admin-bar.php on line 79

The error does not occur if I use an alphanumeric menu title like `My admin link`.
This is the code I am using in functions.php:

```
function my_admin_bar_menu() {

    global $wp_admin_bar;
    if ( !is_super_admin() || !is_admin_bar_showing() )
        return;

    $wp_admin_bar->add_menu( array(
    'title' => __( '#'),
    'href' => admin_url('myurl.php')));

}

add_action('admin_bar_menu', 'my_admin_bar_menu');
```

Comment: Did you try using the HTML encoding instead ?  &#35;

Comment: Yep, as noted in the first sentence.

Comment: Oop! sorry, dont know how i missed that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem: You must specify an ID in the add_menu array if the title is not alphanumeric. So, this code worked:

```
function my_admin_bar_menu() {

    global $wp_admin_bar;
    if ( !is_super_admin() || !is_admin_bar_showing() )
        return;

    $wp_admin_bar->add_menu( array(
    'title' => __( '#'),
    'id' => __( 'my_menu_item'),
    'href' => admin_url('myurl.php')));

}

add_action('admin_bar_menu', 'my_admin_bar_menu');
```

The only change is the addition of the line containing 'id'.